# Mac os activate click on tap gesture through terminal

Tags: mac, macbook, terminal.app

I want to install mac os sierra, but my trackpad doesnt work with clicks, and I cant find a way to select my hard drive as a destination for the installation during the installation setup with the keyboard.

Comment: Does tapping work? Do you have a mouse that you can plug in and try?

Comment: @slhck It doesnt, also, usb ports are dead.